# How to prompt a free type question with list of options in python inquirer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inquirer

I'm looking for something like this:

```
[?] Question: <free type here or one of choices>
 > 1
   2
   3
```

So the user's answer wont be limited to 1, 2 or 3. But inquirer only lets me do either List or Text. List doesn't allow free type, Text has no choices. Is there a way to do this? Should I give up inquirer in favor of another library?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could offer another option, and then offer free text if they choose that.

```py
import inquirer

choice = inquirer.list_input("What choice?", choices=["1", "2", "3", "Other"])
if choice == "Other":
    result = inquirer.text("Enter text: ")
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but it doesn't fell as best solution to me. I tried to think about custom `render`, but didn't come to any conclusion.